# How to share the common logic between controller in Express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had used the express to build my website, and I have a special require.I had set the routers as follow:

```
/* home */
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    homeRacingHandle(req,res);
});

/* racing list */
app.get('/racing',function (req, res, next) {
    homeRacingHandle(req,res);
});
```

There is just a few differents between the [home page](http://racing.biketo.com/) and the [racing list page](http://racing.biketo.com/racing).
My method to process the common logic is like above.And the homeRacingHandle function according the variable `isHome` to decide which page to render.

```
    var location = req.path.split('?').toString();
    var isHome = location==='/' && true || false;
```

This method works for me.But I don't know wether is a good way to process.Are there any other best practice?

Comment: isn't condition `var isHome = location==='/' && true || false;` should be just `var isHome = location==='/';`?

Comment: en...,you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use currying to simplify this

```
curryHomeRacing = require('./handler');

/* home */
app.get('/', curryHomeRacing('home'));

/* racing list */
app.get('/racing', curryHomeRacing('racing'));
```

In another file handler.js

```
//in handler.js

module.exports = function curryHomeRacing(route){
    return function(req, res) {
        homeRacingHandle(req, res, route);
    };
}

function homeRacingHandle(req, res, route) {
    if (route === 'home') {
        //do home stuff
    } else if (route === 'racing') {
        //do racing stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Good.I think it is more maintainable.Thank you!